# Installing SSRS in SharePoint Integrated Mode requires another license?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sharepoint-2007, ssrs

We have a box whit SQL Server 2005 and another with Microsoft Office SharePoint Services 2007.

If we install SQL Server Reporting Services in the MOSS box, in Sharepoint Integrated Mode, does it require another license, or it only counts the Database Server (in the SQL box)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does.  A better option is to install another instance of reporting server on your existing sql server and integrate that instance

Comment: Is it possible to integrate an instace of SSRS in MOSS, being the two in different boxes?

Comment: Yes see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283190(SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, having a SQL Server and a separate SSRS server will require 2 SQL Server licenses.

Here is where I go this info from:
http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/Special-Considerations.aspx

(see the How to license Reporting Services section)